# Passing array to smart contract from web3

Tags: javascript, arrays, solidity

I'm having a problem passing an array from web3 to smart contract.
I have an array declared as `names=[]` with data parsed as int;

I am planning to send a value to my smart contract with the function:

```
function vote(uint[] memory candID,uint id,uint elid) public {
   //code here
  }
```

using this code in my frontend:

```
await contract.methods.vote([names],BigInt(election),BigInt(electClickedID)).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 3000000 });
```

I always face an error, but when passing data manually, like :

```
await contract.methods.vote([0,1,5],BigInt(election),BigInt(electClickedID)).send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 3000000 });
```

it succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `names` is an empty 1-dimensional array, By wrapping it in the additional `[]` expression, you're effectively passing a 2-dimensional array to the Solidity function.

For example, if the value of `names` was `[0,1,5]`, you'd be passing `[[0,1,5]]` - an array of one item, which [the item] is another array of three items.

Which is not valid, as the Solidity function accepts a 1D array.

**Solution**: Remove the array wrapper.

```
let names = [];

await contract.methods.vote(
    names, // instead of `[names]`
    BigInt(election),
    BigInt(electClickedID)
).send({
    from: accounts[0],
    gas: 3000000
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Petr. Your answer was the very 1st thing I tried and got the same error so I tried passing a variable using [].